# Does CloudStorageAccount automatically pick-up configuration changes?

Tags: azure

I've setup my ConfigurationSettingPublisher and can call FromConfigurationSetting to get my CloudStorageAccount inline with the current configuration - all good.

```
CloudStorageAccount.SetConfigurationSettingPublisher(
            (configName, configSettingPublisher) =>
                {
                    string connectionString = RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue(configName);
                    configSettingPublisher(connectionString);
                });

        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount =
            CloudStorageAccount.FromConfigurationSetting("DataConnectionString");
```

When a configuration change occurs on a deployed package, will that change propagate through to the storageAccount instance above, or do I need to call CloudStorageAccount.FromConfigurationSetting("DataConnectionString") again and recreate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you would need to call `CloudStorageAccount::FromConfigurationSetting` to get a new `CloudStorageAccount` instance with the new settings.